# How to mount a drive in a running FreeDOS?

Tags: mount, freedos

I'm currently using FreeDOS to load USB stick content to a virtual drive. The connected HDD won't get a drive letter, as it is simply not formatted.

After that, I'm using [Drive Snapshot](http://www.drivesnapshot.de/en/commandline.htm) to fill the connected HDD and to clone a partition structure.

After that, I want to copy some files from the virtual drive to the connected HDD. The problem is, that it doesn't get mounted (as there was initially no partition on that HDD).

If I would restart the system, the connected HDD gets mounted and everything's fine. But well, restart is no option.

**How can I subsequently mount a HDD in FreeDOS?**

DOS 6.22 would have got the mount.exe, which can adress a physical drive and mount it. Unfortunatelly it seems as it can't be run under FreeDOS, so I need an alternative.